# What is the complement of ACFG

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, sets

What is the complement of $\mathrm{ACFG} = \{ G \mid G \text{ is a CFG and }L(G) = \Sigma^* \}$?

I think it is $\mathrm{ECFG} = \{ G \mid G\text{ is a CFG and }L(G) = \emptyset \}$.

It makes sense to me because the complement of the empty language is the universal language?

Am I correct?

Comment: Do you know the rule of De Morgan? If $A = \{ x \in X \mid P(x)\}$ then $\overline{A} = \{ x \in X \mid \lnot P(x)\}$. You did not invert $P$ correctly, and you don't state $X$.

Comment: @Raphael This is not really an instance of De Morgan, though certainly De Morgan's rules are good to know.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus In this particular case here, $P$ is of the form $A \land B$ so I think De Morgan's rule is (aside from the definiton I cite) all that's needed.

Comment: @Raphael Fair enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the complement of a set is only defined when there is an (understood) universal set. In this case, the universal set is probably the set of all context-free grammars, but it could plausibly be the set of all grammars.

The complement of a set $A$ given a universal set $U$ is defined as the set of elements in $U$ but not in $A$; it is understood that all elements in $A$ are also in $U$. So if $U$ is the set of all context-free grammars, then the complement of ACFG is the set of all context-free grammars $G$ such that $L(G) \neq \Sigma^*$.
If $U$ is the set of all grammars then the complement of ACFG is slightly more complicated: it consists of all non-context-free grammars together with all context-free grammars $G$ such that $L(G) \neq \Sigma^*$.

If $G$ is a context-free grammar and $L(G) = \emptyset$ then $G$ certainly belongs to the complement of ACFG<sup>1</sup>; but other context-free grammars also belong there.

<sup>1</sup><sub>This actually depends on your definition of grammar and on the value of $\Sigma$. If $\Sigma$ is understood and non-empty then what I wrote is correct; if $\Sigma$ is part of the grammar and is always non-empty, again what I wrote is correct; but if $\Sigma$ could be empty, then $\Sigma^* = \emptyset$, so what I wrote is wrong.</sub>

Comment: So If U is the set of all context free grammars, then complement of AFCG is the language of ∅? Can I say that this statement is true under that condition : (the complement of AFCG is EFCG).

Comment: No, try to read my answer again.

Comment: Ah I understand now, EFCG (the empty set) belongs to the complement of AFCG but so do all the other CFG G such that L(G) ≠ Σ∗. Thus then  complement to AFCG is CFG B = {B | B is a CFG and L(B) ≠ Σ∗} ?

Comment: Right, you got it now.